# What is the equivalent of the Linux command "sudo fdisk -l" in MacOS?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, fdisk

In Linux, the command `sudo fdisk -l` produces an output that lists all the disks and partitions in the computer. Here is an example:

[image: Example of fdisk -l output]

If I try to use `sudo fdisk -l` in MacOS X 10.7.5, the output is the following one:

```
fdisk: illegal option -- l
usage: fdisk [-ieu] [-f mbrboot] [-c cyl -h head -s sect] [-S size] [-r] [-a style] disk
    -i: initialize disk with new MBR
    -u: update MBR code, preserve partition table
    -e: edit MBRs on disk interactively
    -f: specify non-standard MBR template
    -chs: specify disk geometry
    -S: specify disk size
    -r: read partition specs from stdin (implies -i)
    -a: auto-partition with the given style
    -d: dump partition table
    -y: don't ask any questions
    -t: test if disk is partitioned
`disk' is of the form /dev/rdisk0.
auto-partition styles:
  boothfs     8Mb boot plus HFS+ root partition (default)
  hfs         Entire disk as one HFS+ partition
  dos         Entire disk as one DOS partition
  raid        Entire disk as one 0xAC partition
```

Is there a command in MacOS to replicate the behavior of `fdisk -l` in Linux?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the 'diskutil' tool for that:

```
% diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *498.9 GB   disk1
```

Comment: @VitoShadow - Make sure to accept the correct answer please (I think you can at your level).

Comment: But what if I want to know the endblock of a partition?

Answer (score 14):

As far as I remember...

**For Mac OS X:**

1. `diskutil` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html)) is a command-line tool for everything Mac OS X can handle, i.e. it will provide as much or more than Disk Utility can do graphically.
2. For MS-DOS MBR (Master Boot Record) partitioned drives, use `fdisk` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pdisk.8.html)).
3. For Apple APM (Apple Partition Map) partitioned drives, use `pdisk` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdisk.8.html)).
4. For Apple and (U)EFI GPT (GUID Partition Table) partitioned drives, use `gpt` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/gpt.8.html)).

If you want a GPT command that is fdisk-like, you should try `gdisk` "GPT fdisk" from Rod Smith. You can find [(important) associated information here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and [download information here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/download.html).

**For Linux:**

Modern Linux uses `parted` for partitioning, so `fdisk` may still be around, but you would really want to use `parted` instead.

- [GNU Parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) `parted` supports all common partition tables, including MBR, APM and GPT. Most Linux distributions have good manuals for the use of `parted`, i.e. during installation, but I always recommend reading the wikipages from [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Parted)—IMHO they are the best, except that this particular one is currently not very up-to-date (Dec 30 2016)!
- `fdisk` is for MBR partitions only. If you try to change the partition table on a GPT partitioned disk, you will instead corrupt the "protective MBR" which is part of the GPT specification. `parted` will prevent you from doing that!
- `pdisk` has been ported from Darwin (the BSD base of Mac OS X) to Linux, so you could also use `pdisk` to create an APM partition table and manage its partitions. The problem is that modern Linux distributions don't include a precompiled package with `pdisk` anymore. *[Status of pdisk](http://cantaforda.com/eryk/linux/pdisk/index.html)*
- `mac-fdisk` is the way to go on Linux/​PowerPC. Most x86 (and x64) distributions don't include `mac-fdisk` because it is big-endian only. Looking at [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mac-fdisk) you see that only powerpc/​powerpc64 packages are available, except for experimental packages for m68k, but not x86.
  The only Linux I know of that has a working `mac-fdisk` on x86/​amd64 is [Gentoo Linux](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-fs/mac-fdisk).
- For GPT partitions `parted` does a great job. If you want an fdisk-like command-line tool, you can use either [`gpt`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gpt) or [`gdisk`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gdisk), although there might be more...

**To answer your question:**

`fdisk` on macOS (previously OS X, originally Mac OS X) acts just the same, but you should check for the partitioning scheme used:

1. x86-PCs (16-Bit, 32-Bit "i386" and 64-Bit "x64") with BIOS use(d) **Master Partition Record** (MBR).
2. Intel Itanium (IA-64), x86-PCs (IA-32, *this includes 64-Bit i.e. amd64 i.e. x64 i.e. x86-64*) with UEFI and Intel-Macs, all of them use EFI/​UEFI (*Universal* Extensible Firmware Interface), use the **GUID Partition Table** (GPT).
3. Apple Macintosh running on m86k (Motorola 68000 series of processors) and PowerPC use **Apple Partition Map** (APM).

This doesn't limit the particular partitioning scheme of external drives, naturally, since all of those computers can use each partitioning scheme on external media **if** the operating system supports it. But for internal drives, more specifically: boot drives, only the one partitioning scheme can be used.

Therefor: if you use `fdisk` on a Mac on an internal drive, you will have no luck, since there is no MBR on that drive. It is either APM or GPT. Likewise, if you use `fdisk` on a modern PC with UEFI (or an Intel Mac with EFI) you will only see the protective MBR of the GPT, not the real partition table.

For creating/​managing partitions, running `fdisk` on an external drive that uses MBR partitioning will work on macOS like it does on Linux.

For listing existing partitions on macOS (Mac OS X), use `sudo diskutil list` (see also [this great article at OSXDaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/01/list-all-mounted-drives-and-their-partitions-from-the-terminal/)). On Linux, the equivilant is `sudo parted -l`, or if you want a specific drive only, `sudo parted /dev/sda print`.

Comment: And let’s not forget about the [CoreStorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Storage) logical volume manager.

Comment: Reading though all this again, I realize that the short answer to the question really is to use `diskutil`. What I intended to point out was that `fdisk` may list partitions on Linux and obviously not on macOS, but using `fdisk` is risky because it is limited to MBR partitions. Modern drives come GPT partitioned– `fdisk` is out-dated and thus becomes dangerous since it will only list the protective MBR part of the GPT. Linux versions of `fdisk` have been modified to show GPT partitions as well, but macOS uses `diskutil`, so it seems there never was real need to use `-l` with `fdisk` anyway.

Comment: It gets even more confusing because there are GPT-capable versions of `fdisk` for Linux. Personally, I think it’s vastly superior to `parted`, too.

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, like I mentioned, some Linux versions of `fdisk` have been modified for use with GPT. IMHO the only really great tool for GPT on Linux and macOS is `gdisk` i.e. “gpt-fdisk”, but `gpt` will also work and on Linux-only `parted` will do the job right. It gets even more complicated with stuff like BootCamp or other multiboot setups, not to mention non-standard alignment and 4k sectors _aka_ “Advanced Format”. I just find it interesting that `fdisk`—clearly a history MS-DOS name for a partitioning tool—is still in peoples minds for listing partitions, even on modern systems.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use fdisk /dev/rdisk0 to get CHS and end block of a partition

```
LiuJianweis-iMac:~ liujianwei$ sudo fdisk /dev/rdisk0
Password:
Disk: /dev/rdisk0   geometry: 15566/255/63 [250069680 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
        Starting       Ending
 : id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  250069679] <Unknown ID>
2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0     -      0] unused      
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: I got `fdisk: /dev/rdisk0: Operation not permitted` even if sudo password is given

Comment: Works for me.  Perhaps it only works for MBR partitions?  Actually I just used `/dev/disk0` rather than `/dev/rdisk0`.  I'm not sure what the added `r` implies; I've never used it.